# Meteor : best practice for modifying Mongo query result before template takes it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor, conceptual

Learning Meteor, I'm still getting stuck in conceptual quagmires.

I have a collection in which each item has an array called "props" that holds zero or more property names: loudmouth, fixer, networker, outcast, etc.

I also have a collection of property objects, each of which is associated with a single glyph-icon.

Right now, my template displays the data items as an unordered list of <li></li> lines that include the property identifiers.   I want to replace the property identifiers with the corresponding icon HTML

```
{name: "loudmouth", icon: "bullhorn", other: "rtgb"}
{name: "fixer", icon: "wrench", other: "iun"}
{name: "networker", icon: "link", other: "retf"}
{name: "outcast", icon: "ban-circle", other: "vcfdds"}
```

So this ...

```
<li>AAA loudmouth fixer outcast</li>
<li>BBB fixer networker</li>
```

... should become this ...

```
<li>AAA <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
<li>BBB <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
```

This is not a SQL join; I'm adding attributes to each returned result item. What's the best way to do it?

I tried a couple of ways, but they got really messy.

1) The first was a crude inner/outer loop job in the client.  For each data item in the outer, I'd append <span> tags concatenated from strings from the inner loop.  This seemed to give me some kind of race condition, with spurious "undefined"s. (I'm not yet clear about its sychronicity rules).  Should I pre-fetch the properties collection into a name/value map object?  Also, strangely, my HTML showed the text of the <span> tags rather than icons?!?!  Huh?

2)  I then tried doing it on the server-side using Meteor.method and Meteor.call.  I could not get data back synchronously, and don't really understand how one populates a template asychronously (from a callback).  Do you populate an array during Template.mine.created() and then return the array from a Template.mine.helper?   Am I right that the Meteor.method / Meteor.call combination is supposed to be used for altering back-end data, **NOT** for retrieving back-end data?

Does anyone know of a good tutorial about this kind of thing?  How would you do it?

I hope this won't get rejected as 'opinion-based', I'm sure all valid alternatives will help others who have related problems to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a parametrised template:

```
<template name="glyph">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{icon this}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</template>
```

Add a helper function like:

```
Template.glyph.helpers({
    icon: function(name) {
            return <Iconcollection>.findOne({name:name}).icon
    }   
});
```

And then you can do something like this in your template:

```
{{> glyph 'fixer'}}
```

or, if the argument comes from your iterator object

```
{{> glyph name}}
```

(assuming your object has a `.name` property)

In any case, I'd suggest you re-read and experiment with helpers and reactivity in Meteor. Since you already have the collection in the client, you'd usually solve this sort of problem with just a helper function. Meteor (re)calculates as the collections get updated, so you never really have to worry about it.

Comment: This is really interesting.  But, why {{icon this}} instead of {{icon}}  ?  So, in fact, I'd have to do :   <li> {{fullName}}  {{#each prop}} {{> glyph name}} {{/each}} </li>.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, you can just do `{{icon}}`, as the template context ("data") carries over into the embedded template, I forgot about that. And yes, if `prop.name` exists, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check my understanding:
1 user has 1 property.
1 property has 1 `name`, 1 `icon`, 1 `other`

If this is the case, check your 3NF at the door & just embed those in the user document. So your schema might look like this:

```
{userId: 'asldkfjz', 
 userName: 'Jonny', 
 properties: {
   name: "loudmouth", 
   icon: "bullhorn", 
   other: "rtgb"
 }
}
```

With MongoDB, you always need to weigh the cost of space with the cost of access. Storing 1 foreign key + an extra subscription is *probably* (most definitely) more expensive than 3 strings, right?

Next, here's how I would set up your templates:

```
{{#each user}}
    {{>formatRow icon=properties.icon name=properties.name other=properties.other}}
{{/each}}

<template name="formatRow">
  <div class="blah">
    <li>{{name}} 
        <span class="glyphicon {{icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
```

I create a template that takes in 3 variables: `icon`, `name`, and `other`. Then, in my main template, I pass in those variables. I separate the two steps because chances are you'll have a lot more junk than just `li` and `span` later on, or you'll want to do this in another template, and this keeps them modular.

The only thing left to do is set up a template helper with access to the collection:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  user: function () {
    return users.find();
  }
});
```

Learn more at:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md

Comment: Sorry but, one user as an array of properties :  <li>AAA loudmouth fixer outcast</li>

Comment: you're storing an HTML string in your collection?

Comment: It's perfectly possible, but doesn't affect the conceptual issues I am trying to solve.

Comment: B.t.w I really appreciate the detail of your answer, but the real problem is the right way to substitute icon names for zero or more property names  at some point in the data-flow from back-end to front-end.